# Javascript doesn't load the new location

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, window.location

This is my main function, using jquery and jquery-ui. The problem is that it should load the new adress when clicking a link (after the animation "desaparecer"). Links have a rel tag which contains the number of the "articulo".

```
    $(function () {
        function aparecer () {
            $("#centro").show('drop','fast')
        }   
        function desaparecer () {
            $("#centro").hide('drop', 'fast', 'carga ()')
        };
        function cargar () {
            window.location = 'index.php?articulo=' + a.attr('rel');
        };
        $("a").click(function () {
            var a = $(this);
            desaparecer();
            return false;
        });
        aparecer();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared "a" inside the click handler for the `<a>` tag(s).  Move that out to the outside of those functions:

```
$(function () {
    var a;

    function aparecer () {
```

then change the click hander:

```
    $("a").click(function () {
        a = $(this);  // no "var" here
        desaparecer();
        return false;
    });
```

Because "a" is *inside* that click handler, the "cargar" function wouldn't see it. But declared outside *both* functions, they'll both have access to the same variable.

Also it looks like "cargar" is misspelled in the "disappear" function.  It shouldn't really be in a string like that anyway; it can look like this:

```
    function desaparecer () {
        $("#centro").hide('drop', 'fast', cargar)
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

`carga` does not equal `cargar`

And the callback, according to the jQuery docs, is supposed to be a function, not a string to be `eval`ed.

```
$("#centro").hide('drop', 'fast', cargar)
```